# Play audio url using xamarin MediaPlayer

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, audio-streaming

Why xamarin MediaPlayer (on Xamarin.Android) can play audio as a stream from a link like this (mediaUrl1) :
https://ia800806.us.archive.org/15/items/Mp3Playlist_555/AaronNeville-CrazyLove.mp3

But can't do it from a link like this (mediaUrl2): 
http://api-streaming.youscribe.com/v1/products/2919465/documents/3214936/audio/stream

```
private MediaPlayer player;
//..
player = new MediaPlayer();
player.SetAudioStreamType(Stream.Music);
//..
await player.SetDataSourceAsync(ApplicationContext, Android.Net.Uri.Parse(mediaUrl));
//..
player.PrepareAsync();
//..
```

Is there a way to play the link above (mediaUrl2) without (of course) downloading the file first?

Here is the full [source](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/AndroidStreamingAudio/tree/master/Part%201%20-%20Simple%20Streaming) of the sample i am using. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> http://api-streaming.youscribe.com/v1/products/2919465/documents/3214936/audio/stream

That is an HTTP `mpga` stream and is not directly supported by any of the Android APIs that I know of and thus is not supported by `MediaPlayer` (consult the [Android Support Media Formats](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html) for further reading).

You can review the `logcat` output of your `MediaPlayer` code and you will see output like:

```
[MediaPlayerNative] start called in state 4, mPlayer(0x8efb7240)
[MediaPlayerNative] error (-38, 0)
[MediaPlayer] Error (-38,0)
[MediaHTTPConnection] readAt 1161613 / 32768 => java.net.ProtocolException
[MediaHTTPConnection] readAt 1161613 / 32768 => java.net.ProtocolException
[MediaPlayerNative] error (1, -2147483648)
[MediaPlayer] Error (1,-2147483648)
```

Google's Android ExoPlayer can stream that media format properly.

This is a **really simple and very crude** example of ExoPlayer, but it will show you that it does play that stream:

#### ExoPlayer Example:

```
var mediaUrl = "http://api-streaming.youscribe.com/v1/products/2919465/documents/3214936/audio/stream";
var mediaUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(mediaUrl);

var userAgent = Util.GetUserAgent(this, "ExoPlayerDemo");
var defaultHttpDataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(userAgent);
var defaultDataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, null, defaultHttpDataSourceFactory);
var extractorMediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(mediaUri, defaultDataSourceFactory, new DefaultExtractorsFactory(), null, null);
var defaultBandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
var adaptiveTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(defaultBandwidthMeter);
var defaultTrackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(adaptiveTrackSelectionFactory);

exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.NewSimpleInstance(this, defaultTrackSelector);
exoPlayer.Prepare(extractorMediaSource);
exoPlayer.PlayWhenReady = true;
```

Note: `exoPlayer` is a class-level variable of `SimpleExoPlayer` type

Note: this is using the `Xamarin.Android` binding libraries from the `Xam.Plugins.Android.ExoPlayer` package

#### ExoPlayer Docs:

- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer